# Symfony 2 setting up translation files

Tags: symfony, internationalization, yaml

I am failing to setup translation for my Symfony 2 project. I have manually created a folder inside `app\Resources\translations\message.en.yml` and it's content:

```
base:
    title:
        homePage: TeamERP IMS for BA
```

Then on the base twig template inside my bundle I am trying to call it:

```
    <title>
        {% block title %}
            {{ base.title.homePage|trans }}
        {% endblock %}
    </title>
```

Then on the `config.yml` I has the following:

```
framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: en }
```

I am getting this error:

```
 Variable "base" does not exist in TeamERPBaseBundle::base.html.twig at line 7
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** after fixing the problem here:

```
{{ 'base.title.homePage'|trans }}
```

I stopped getting the error, thanks for that. now the page is not giveng the error but not loading the page with the warning in the logs fine:

```
[2015-05-01 12:42:57] translation.WARNING: Translation not found. {"id":"base.title.homePage","domain":"messages","locale":"en"} []
[2015-05-01 12:42:57] translation.WARNING: Translation not found. {"id":"Home","domain":"messages","locale":"en"} []
```

Edit2: There was some kind of problem with my version of symfony 2.6. I just did a `composer update` due to [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12941), and it started working. normaly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it should be `messages.en.yml` as indicated by @xurshid29, but most important it should be

```
<title>
    {% block title %}
        {{ 'base.title.homePage'|trans }}
    {% endblock %}
</title>
```

inside the template. The value passed to the `trans` filter must be a string but `base.title.homePage|trans` would be expanded to something similar to `$base->getTitle()->getHomepage()` because it's a Twig variable syntax. That's why you're getting the error message `Variable "base" does not exist`.

Comment: I changed the fine name and also did this `{{ 'base.title.homePage'|trans }}`. I am not getting the error any more but when I load the page the title is showing `base.title.homePage` and not `TeamERP IMS for BA`.

Comment: Did you enable translations as described here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/book/translation.html#configuration

Comment: @wti Documentation says `framework: -> translator: -> FALLBACKS: [en] (with array values)`, but in my local project I set it as `framework: -> translator: -> FALLBACK: en (without S)`, and in your config you're mixing these, like `framework: -> translator: -> FALLBACKS: en`. I think this is causing the issue..

Comment: I have done: `framework:    translator: { fallback: en }` and it does not work. as well as `framework: translator: { fallback: [en] }` and with the `s` as well. how do I know if Symfony 2 is loading the translations?

Answer (score 0):

Rename `message.en.yml` to `messages.en.yml`, it should work.

Comment: @wti Look at Stefan Gehrig's answer

Answer (score 0):

The format of your yaml file is imho not correct and the translation in twig is wrong.

**message.en.yml**

```
base.title.homePage: TeamERP IMS for BA
```

**your.twig.html**

```
<title>
    {% block title %}
        {{ 'base.title.homePage' | trans }}
    {% endblock %}
</title>
```

You can use the Translation component as you like, but better is to write down correct sentences in your main language (TeamERP IMS for BA) and translate them. Think of giving a translation file away to native speaker who should translate it:

**message.de.yml**

```
TeamERP IMS for BA: TeamERP IMS für BA
```

**your.twig.html**

```
<title>
    {% block title %}
        {% trans %}TeamERP IMS for BA{% endtrans %}
    {% endblock %}
</title>
```

And of course check the domains `{% trans_default_domain "message" %}`

Comment: Your first assumption is wrong. Symfony's YAML loader supports structured translation files as seen here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html.

Comment: I have tried this as well: `base.title.homePage: TeamERP IMS for BA` it does not work, check ot the Edit on my original question.

Comment: @StefanGehrig thanks, didn't know and used it that way.

Comment: @wti as I've mentioned at the end, check your translation domain.